# TypeScript: why is my object "undefined" when I log it?

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gujdbh?file=src/app/app.component.html) with a button you can click that passes a value to the controller, and a function in the controller that assigns the value to an object. But TypeScript says that my object is undefined and won't let me assign values to its properties.

I followed the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html) for object types:

```
person: { name: string; age: number }
```

I'm expecting to see in the console:

```
Button clicked!
42
{ foo: undefined; bar: undefined }
{ foo: 42; bar: true }
```

But instead I get:

```
Button clicked!
42
undefined
ERROR Error: cannot set property 'foo' of undefined
```

What's wrong?

`app.component.html`

```html
<button (click)="clickMe(42)">Click me!</button>
```

`app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {
  myObject: { foo: number; bar: boolean };

  clickMe(value) {
    console.log("Button clicked!");
    console.log(value);
    console.log(this.myObject);
    this.myObject.foo = value;
    this.myObject.bar = true;
    console.log(this.myObject);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is undefined, you have only defined it’s type but not it’s value, that’s why when you try to assign a value to it’s properties you get the error. Initialize it in your constructor this.myObject = { foo: null, bar: null } or you can set the properties as optional and initialize it like this.myObject = {}

Generally it’s better to let TypeScript infer the type when possible, in this case, instead of the : type definition you can simply write myObject = { foo: value, bar: value } and TypeScript will infer the type while giving it a value at the same time.

Comment: I tried to initialize the object with myObject: { foo: number; bar: boolean } = { foo: undefined; bar: undefined } but that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! Remember undefined means no declaration or you can see it as “no space in memory for this variable” and null is an empty value with memory space, declaring them as undefined would mean that they don’t exist, but in your type declaration you state that they have to exist. that’s why it won’t let you. If you change the properties to optional you’ll see that you will now be able to set them to undefined